# Reading different part of .plist depending on Selected segmentIndex

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist, uisegmentedcontrol, selectedindex

I've created a plist. I want to use a UIsegmentedControl with 3 sections. Each section should load a different part of the plist into a tableView. Can I please get some advise about how to achieve this(**loading a different part of the plist into a tableView**)?

Please take a look at the image for more info.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read the three items in an array.
When switching the control you simply repopulate the tableview with the correct index from your items array.

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example please.

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials on the web: search how to read the plist, how to handle the UISegmentControl switch and how to populate and reload an UITableView; than combine all and write your code.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I know it's a beginners question. Thats exactly what I am. I've also found the Apple devs resource which is also pretty clear. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5